# Can anyone explain the anomalous behavior of LU decomposition in Revol R?

Tags: r, matrix, decomposition

A simple matrix benchmark test has indicated that *Revolution Analytics* `R 2.13.2`'s
LU decomposition is nearly 5 times slower than matrix multiplication.
Theory and many years of practice show that LU should be 1/3 to 2/3 the time for `A*A`.

Revo R and Matlab are using *Intel's Math Kernel* for this test.
`R 2.14.1` is not using a kernel. Everything is 64-bit.

The anomaly shows up in Table 2 below. This is Table 1 normalized about `A*A` . There are other (apparent) anomalies but LU is the most glaring one.

```
                        Table 1 (secs)

                    A*A     LU     A\b    Det   Inv
----------------------------------------------------
R 2.14.1           0.757   0.43   0.45   0.20  1.11
Revo R 2.13.2      0.063   0.35   0.11   0.03  0.14
Matlab 2011b       0.062   0.08   0.10   0.07  0.16
----------------------------------------------------
Averaged over 20 runs on a 1000x1000 random matrix


                       Table 2 (normalized)

                    A*A     LU     A\b    Det   Inv
----------------------------------------------------
R 2.14.1             1     0.57   0.19   0.26  1.47
Revol R 2.13.2       1     4.67*  1.58   1.33  2.17
Matlab 2011b         1     0.67   1.72   0.61  1.68
----------------------------------------------------
Note: x = A\b in Matlab is x <- solve(A,b) in R.
```

---

**UPDATE**: I have followed Simon Urbanek's advice and replaced `LUP = expand(lu(Matrix(A)));` with `lu(A)`; The Revo R rows are now

```
                    Revol R 2.13.2

              A*A    LU     A\b    Det   Inv
            ---------------------------------
  time       0.104  0.107  0.110  0.042  0.231  
  norm time  1.000  1.034  1.060  0.401  2.232
```

---

Time in seconds on a

```
Dell Precision 690, 2 x Intel®  Xeon® E53405 CPU @ 2.33GHz,
16GB ram, 2 Processors, 8 Cores and 8 Threads, 
Windows 7 Prof., 64-bit
```

A work-in-progress report that contains tables and the code used are [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/78367129/OConnor-X220-Benchmarks).

---

**UPDATE 2**:

I have modified the matrix benchmark  to test *Matrix Decompositions* only. These are the foundations on which all other matrix algorithms are built, and if these are shaky then all other algorithms will be shaky too.

I have changed to a brand new

```
Lenovo ThinkPad X220, Intel Core i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz, 
8GB ram, 1 Processor, 2 Cores and 4 Threads
Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit.
```

**Note**: The `Core i7` processor has *Intel's Turbo Boost* which increases the clock rate up to 3.5GHz if it senses a high demand. As far as I know, Turbo Boost is not under program(mer) control in any of the three systems.

These changes will, I hope, make the results more useful.

```
                          Table 3. Times(secs)

                  A*A    chol(A)   lu(A)    qr(A)    svd(A)   eig(A)   Total
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
R 2.14.1         0.904    0.157    0.260    0.568    4.260    6.967    13.11
Revol R 2.13.2   0.121    0.029    0.062    0.411    1.623    3.265     5.51   
Matlab 2011b     0.061    0.014    0.033    0.056    0.342    0.963     1.47       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Times(secs) averaged over 20  runs



                          Table 4. Times(normalized)

                  A*A    chol(A)   lu(A)    qr(A)    svd(A)  eig(A)   Total
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
R 2.14.1         1.000    0.174    0.288    0.628    4.714    7.711   14.52
Revol R 2.13.2   1.000    0.237    0.515    3.411   13.469   27.095   45.73
Matlab 2011b     1.000    0.260    0.610    0.967    5.768   16.774   25.38
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     Times(secs) averaged over 20  runs
```

We can see from Table 4 that the spurious anomaly has disappeared and that all system behave as the theory predicts.

```
                          Table 5. Times/Matlab Times

                  A*A    chol(A)   lu(A)    qr(A)    svd(A)  eig(A)   Total
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
R 2.14.1          15      11         8       10       12       7        9
Revol R 2.13.2     2       2         2        7        5       3        4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         Rounded to the nearest integer
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW you're not measuring the time of the decomposition, but the overhead you create by converting the matrices all the time. In regular R:

```
# actual lu call
> system.time(lu(A))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.136   0.000   0.139 
# your code
> system.time(expand(lu(Matrix(A))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.536   0.000   0.537
```

so chances are you're creating the overhead yourself. This matters in particular when the decomposition is fast. Also note that taking about performance of "R" is ambiguous since the performance of R itself varies strongly depending on which BLAS you use.

(As a side note - you may want to use `system.time` in your benchmarks - also of interest to you could be the `microbenchmark` R package)

Comment: Spot on! The expand(...) is adding the overhead. I'll update the table above. Also, thanks for your `microbenchmark' tip.

Comment: FWIW the main overhead is in `Matrix`, the overhead is `expand` in much smaller